# Can alphafold 2 be used to identify residues important for binding?

Tags: alphafold

I am interested in using AlphaFold2 to identify residues within a homodimer that are important for the protein-protein interaction. I have been able to use ColabFold to produce a predicted dimer structure - however, as far as I can tell AlphaFold does not actually identify the residues or regions that are actually important for binding. Is there a way to manipulate the software to do this?
Thanks!